# How add existing file to Different Visual Studio Project Programmatically

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am newbie. 
I want to create a Visual C++ project as programmatically. 
I have tried EnvDTE objects but they are working on instance of current solution but I want to edit different project file of different solution that not opened anywhere.

How can I get instance of different project to edit it?

And I am using Visual Studio 2013 Express. Is there any limimation for it? Should I use VSPackage's?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In general I would recommend considering a build system like CMake or Scons. It allows to generate build scripts for arbitrary platform (as such it includes MSVS solution files).

However, you might simply edit project file with some script or program. Project files are plain xml files and it's easy to add external files.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ClCompile Include="some_file.cpp" />
</ItemGroup>
```